# Master report is not generating for all suites with HTML REPORTER (wdio5)

Tags: image-comparison, wdio-v5

I have setting up a configuration in 'wdio.conf.js' for "rpii html reporter". But its not generating master report for all suites.

```
const { ReportAggregator, HtmlReporter } = require('@rpii/wdio-html-reporter');
exports.config = {

    reporters: ['spec', [HtmlReporter, {
        debug: true,
        outputDir: './reports/html-reports/',
        filename: 'report.html',
        reportTitle: 'Test Report Title',
        showInBrowser:true
    }
    ]],

    onPrepare: function (config, capabilities) {

        let reportAggregator = new ReportAggregator({
            outputDir: './reports/html-reports/',
            filename: 'master-report.html',
            reportTitle: 'Master Report'
        });
        reportAggregator.clean() ;

        global.reportAggregator = reportAggregator;
    },

    onComplete: function(exitCode, config, capabilities, results) {
        (async () => {
            await global.reportAggregator.createReport( {
                config: config,
                capabilities: capabilities,
                results : results
            });
        })();
    }
}
```

I expect single report with multiple test cases. But I'm getting multiple reports for each test cases.

Answer (score 3):

The topic is pretty old atm, but I just addressed a similar issue in my project - cannot generate the report at all. In most of the case, it is just a matter of configuration, but there is no solid document or guideline for this painful wdio reporter configuration. So here I am, after a whole week of research and testing around, these are viable config you will need and other fellows out there who is/was facing the same issue.

First, let assume your project structure would be something like the below tree

```
.
├── some_folder1
│   ├── some_sub_folder1
│   ├── some_sub_folder2
├── some_folder2
├── @report
│   ├── html-reports
│   ├── template
│   │   ├── sanity-mobile-report-template.hbs
│   │   ├── wdio-html-template.hbs
├── specs
│   ├── test1
│   │   ├── test1.doSuccess.spec.js
│   │   ├── test1.doFail.spec.js
│   ├── test2
│   │   ├── test2.doSuccess.spec.js
│   │   ├── test2.doFail.spec.js
├── node-modules
├── package.json
```

Second, you should have templates for your reports, in my case, it is located in **@report/template** `wdio-html-template.hbs` and `sanity-mobile-report-template.hbs` for `HtmlReporter` and `ReportAggregator` respectively. As Rich Peters has notices above

> Each suite is executed individually and an html and json file are
> generated. wdio does not aggregate the suites, so this is done by the
> report aggregator collecting all the files and creating an aggregate
> file when complete

The `HtmlReporter` will actually need to find it template for generating the content for each .spec file, then there is a need for another template requested by `ReportAggregator`

[image]

Third, you need correct specs and suites declaration in your wdio config, generic for specs, and file specifically for suites.
[image]

Final, run your test using `--suite` parameter, reference to wdio [guideline](https://webdriver.io/docs/organizingsuites.html)

My final project structure would look like this, notice the changes

```
.
├── some_folder1
│   ├── some_sub_folder1
│   ├── some_sub_folder2
├── some_folder2
├── @report
│   ├── html-reports
│   ├── ├── screenshots
│   ├── ├── suite-0-0
│   ├── ├── ├── 0-0
│   ├── ├── ├── ├── report.html
│   ├── ├── ├── ├── report.json
│   ├── ├── ├── 0-1
│   ├── ├── ├── ├── report.html
│   ├── ├── ├── ├── report.json
│   ├── ├── master-report.html
│   ├── ├── master-report.json
│   ├── template
│   │   ├── sanity-mobile-report-template.hbs
│   │   ├── wdio-html-template.hbs
├── specs
│   ├── test1
│   │   ├── test1.doSuccess.spec.js
│   │   ├── test1.doFail.spec.js
│   ├── test2
│   │   ├── test2.doSuccess.spec.js
│   │   ├── test2.doFail.spec.js
├── node-modules
├── package.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Each suite is executed individually and an html and json file are generated.  wdio does not aggregate the suites, so this is done by the report aggregator collecting all the files and creating an aggregate file when complete.